# Asp.net MVC client validation, no client validation with sub-items?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using asp.net mvc 3 for a project and already using the server and client validation on several pages. It works fine. But this time, I've a special case:

Items in the view are bounds to the model and also to some of its properties.

one example:

```
public class MyModelView{
   [Required]
   [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
   public String Name{get;set;}
   public DetailsObject Details{get;set;}
}
public class DetailsObject{
   [Required]
   [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
   public String PropertyOne{get;set;}
   [Required]
   [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
   public String PropertyTwo{get;set;}
}
```

and in the view I've "bindings on all elements

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Details.PropertyOne)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Details.PropertyTwo)
```

The problem is that I don't get any client validations. The server validation is still working fine for all properties.

I've the jquery validate unobtrusive included. How do you manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several places you should check

web.config should have those lines

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

check the javascripts to be included in right order

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

also as a reminder (as I don't see the whole view file) place `ValidationMessageFor` helpers to see validation errors

Comment: I'm sorry, in fact I was only missing the css. It was "working" on other pages, because on other pages I needed confirmation message, so I was getting a visual feedback.